# Proper way to handle authentication to external API from Nestjs API

Tags: api, axios, interceptor, nestjs

I have a public NestJs API, so no authentication required, but from this api I need to make requests to external API, this api has an auth endpoint with basic authentication (user and pass) and return a Bearer token. What is the proper way to hadle this situation? Maybe a global interceptor to intercept all request and verify the token status and if is expired make another auth request to renoval token and continue...

Ex:
Get products request => My API => Verify token (valid) => continue external API => (expired) => Auth request get token (External API) => continue previous request (External API).

I would also like to know good practices to store the access token.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use an interceptor. About storing the access token if it is needed once per application startup you can save it to the environment or to some cache.
Check out our solution:
https://github.com/valueadd-poland/pimp-my-pr/blob/master/libs/server/shared/core/src/lib/github/interceptors/github-auth.interceptor.ts

Comment: It's a good example, but I need some mechanism to refresh the token as has a session expire time and always the same credential wil be used.

Comment: you can catch request exception inside the interceptor and trigger action for token refreshing.

Comment: Why not using redis for this ?